# How to quickly update a Smart Group?

Tags: smartgroups

On CiviCRM 5.6.0

I have a Smart Group based upon custom_param1=1 (as an example).

I change some values of custom_param1, to update my Smart Group in order to send a mail to its updated members.

But the Smart Group is not updated immediately (I have to wait 5 minutes before it is)

How can I force its update to have it immediately ?

(rebuilding the smart group cache has no effect)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the Civi cache doesn't work? It should.

Comment: can you run cron faster?

Comment: @Andy : I did not expect cleaning the civi cache would work (while rebuilding the smart group cache does not), but actually, you look right ; I will test more extensively. BTW, do you know how I can clean the cache from a php program (I am not really a programmer, but may be able to with a little help) ?

Comment: @Sean : running CRON has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Change the 'Smart group cache timeout' which is in Administer/Customise data and screens/Search Preferences  The default is 5 minutes but I normally set this to 1 for my clients. It can be set to zero but this isn't recommended according to this screen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of openning the Smart Group (e.g. /civicrm/group/search?force=1&context=smog&**gid=341**&component_mode=1), you can call its pertaining Search (e.g. /civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1&force=1&**ssID=263**).

You can get the Search Id (ssID) :

- either via "Edit Smart Group Searc Criteria ..." button (which calls the associated Search URL)
- or in the civicrm_group table : saved_search_id field

**NO : this gives erratic results**

Comment: if your last edit means 'this answer does not work' then perhaps it should be deleted as an Answer and added as a Comment or an 'update' on the Question.